# How to get the current spinner value on Android

Tags: android, spinner

does anyone know how to get the current id value from a spinner.

The problem is that the spinner value change dinamically, without interaction with the user, and i need the spinner value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three methods you can use to find out about the current selection:

- [getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem())
- [getSelectedItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId())
- [getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition())

It's up to you to translate one of these into the actual value represented by the Spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Another option avaialable is to use the values passed to the OnItemSelectedListener.

This example uses position without using getSelectedItemPosition() :-

```
// Set Spinner's onItemSelectedListener ie to act when an aisle is selected.
// Note!!! run on post, as a runnable, so that initial onItemSelected event (at initialisation) is not captured.
current_aislelistspinner.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        current_aislelistspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                currentaislelistcursor.moveToPosition(position);
                currentaisleid = currentaislelistcursor.getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX);
                Log.d(Constants.LOG,"ACTIVITY: " + THIS_ACTIVITY + " SECTION: Running - AISLELIST OnItemSelectedLIstener" +
                        "- AILSEID Extracted=" + currentaisleid);
                currentproductsperaisleecursor = shopperdb.getProductsperAisle(currentaisleid);
                current_productsperaislecursoradapter.swapCursor(currentproductsperaisleecursor);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note! as the above is a runnable on the spinner's post event, it doesn't trigger when the spinner is created.